# exec() which/where to mysql php?

Tags: php, command-line

I've seen things like this a few times in code in what seems to be an effort to be cross platform when calling a program like MySQL:

```
if ( $mysql = exec( 'which mysql' ) ) {
    // Use the path returned from 'which'. 
    exec( "$mysql {{{SOME MYSQL CMD HERE}}}" );
} else {
    // The call failed, so try and guess MySQL path.
    exec( "mysql {{{SOME MYSQL CMD HERE}}}" );
}
```

However wouldn't this be pointless? If which is able to guess which mysql path is being used, then the path has already been provided and the 'else' would have worked. If it doesn't exist, neither option would work.

What I'm curious about is if there is ever a case where calling a command line utility like mysql or git directly through exec won't work, but trying to guess the path first through which or where will?

Comment: May be author of this code think about variants when `which` command not exists

Comment: In this case, the MySQL command would be the same, so there's no variance on what's being run, just "which" path it's run with (see what I did there :)

Comment: Please share the code where you have seen this.

Comment: In case of MySQL this is one crap'o'code, if there are native drivers available you should never run from command line. Other than that if it's not detected by `which`, I don't see how would it be guessed in the `else` case.

Comment: Else can be any other alternative, it's just there to illustrate the point... My main question is that if 'which mysql' works, wouldn't just plain 'mysql' work as well?

Comment: As to an example, VaultPress uses a modified version of this method in their restore() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pointless what you are trying. `which` is iterating trough elements of the `$PATH` environment variable and tries to find the a binary called `mysql` there.

If you are just issuing `mysql` (without a path), the shell would do the same as `which` but then executes the command.

---

One **important** thing you must know: Unlike the `glibc` function, PHP's `exec()` executes the `$command` **in a shell** - not directly! You are able to use the binary name without a path because it is executed in a shell and the shell tries to find the binary in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

The else-case is only reached if there is no `which` on your system.

It is bad practise anyway:

If theres `which` but no `mysql` found within the search path, the which-command is successfully executed anyway by `exec` so the first condition is true. But in this case the $mysql-var contains a string with something like "no mysql in YOUR_PATH_HERE". Which will of course result in an error if executed itself.